# Subclassing UITableViewCell on Swift - Error edit UITableView rows

Tags: uitableview, swift

Using Swift: I've hooked up an NSFetchedResultsController to a UITableView, and created a subclass of UITableViewCells for the TableView cells.

The UITableViewCells format and display correctly. But the app crashes as soon as I try editing the rows (adding or deleting).

For testing, I've used the most basic subclass possible: An empty subclass, and it still crashes. The original UITableViewCell works normally.

Any ideas? Swift bug? The crash goes straight to the top of the stack. I get nothing in the console.

Works:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let task = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Tasks
    cell.textLabel.text = task.desc
    return cell
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell2
    let task = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Tasks
    cell.textLabel.text = task.desc
    return cell
}
```

When subclass is:

```
import UIKit

class UITableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create table cells programmatically (not in InterfaceBuilder) you have to register the table cell class with

```
TableView.registerClass(..., forCellReuseIdentifier...)
```

Comment: I had created one, but for the wrong one! That's why UITableViewCell worked, and not UITableViewCell2... Thanks for this, that's the solution.

Comment: Another thing to remember is to write the initialisation for the UITableViewCell on this method:  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) }